# Energy-momentum tensor in two-dimensional spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, field-theory

If we consider the following 2D theory
$$S=\int d^2 x\sqrt{-g}\left(R+\mathcal{L}_{\rm matter}\right).$$

I understand that the gravity is trivial in two-dimensional spacetime because the Einstein tensor vanishes identically. But taking the variation of $\mathcal{L}_{\rm matter}$ with repect to the metric seems to give $T_{\mu\nu}=0$? How to understand this result? Cannot we even have matter in two-dimensional spacetime? What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OP is right: In 2D the matter [SEM tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) $T^{(\rm m)}_{\mu\nu}$ should vanish unless we allow a [cosmological constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations#The_cosmological_constant) $\Lambda$. Then the 2D [EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) becomes $$ \Lambda  g_{\mu\nu}~=~\kappa T^{(\rm m)}_{\mu\nu},\qquad  \kappa~\equiv~\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}, $$
which again has non-trivial solutions.

Comment: If we take the trace, we then get $2\Lambda=T$ (taking $\kappa=1$). For a massive free field, we have $T=m^2\phi^2$ which leads to a trivial solution $\phi=2\Lambda/m^2$, at least classically. Am I right?

Comment: Do you assume that the kinetic term vanishes? What metric do you use?

Comment: No, I did not make such assumption.But I found when we take the trace, the kinematic terms will be canclled out.